# scroll animation not working properly; when i click the link i get directed but with no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

smooth scrolling is not working?? when i click the link to scroll to an element/section it takes me directly to it no smooth scrolling even after changing animation speed to 5000. my scripts are correct so i don't know what to do

this my code below; for query and i have properly tagged my links with a '#' tag and created an ID for each of my elements properly

```
    $(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 5000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
       var target = $(this.hash);
       target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
       if (target.length) {
         $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top
         }, 1000);
         return false;
}}
});
});
```